# More Specific Filesize on Windows

Tags: windows

I'm working between an FTP client and a regular local windows folder. My ftp client in displaying files in "details" mode and showing items like this:

```
 Filename          Filesize          Filetype
+--------------------------------------------+
 main.php          5,988             PHP File
```

The filesize shows me a more specific number than my local windows "details" view:

```
 Filename          Filesize 
+--------------------------+
 main.php          6KB
```

Is there a configuration within my folder-view which will tell me specifically (or more-specifically) how many bytes the file consists of? This helps determining which files are larger when looking between the two views, but when my local view rounds up the number, I can't be completely sure which is larger without going in and checking properties specifically, which is too tasking when you're examining a folder of items.

Comment: Can't you view them side-by-side in your FTP client? Like this: http://i25.tinypic.com/bhx5lj.jpg

Comment: Have you tried Filezilla? It displays the local and the remote directories at the same time and shows the full number of bytes of all files.

Comment: Guess people agree with me ;-)

Comment: I'm using FileZilla presently, but navigating my local directories is sluggish in the left-pane. As a result, I generally have both windows explorer and FileZilla opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the display from kilobytes to bytes in Windows Explorer.

I'm using **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** instead, which is showing the size down to the very last byte. :)

[image]

Oh, and it also is a FTP client ... and you'll have the option to compare files (by size or content)

Comment: and it's also so much more :) +1

Answer (score 0):

[xplorer²](http://zabkat.com/) has this functionality, although explorer does not have the ability to change that default behaviour:

[image]